# How to pass the text as a parameter in cypress get command

Tags: javascript, cypress

I am using Cypress tool in one of my projects and I can find some element containing a text, say XYZ, using something like this -

```
myElement() {
        return cy.get('span:contains("XYZ")');
}
```

.
However, I want to make this method generic by passing this value XYZ as a parameter.
I tried something like this but it did not work -

```
myElement(text) {
        return cy.get('span:contains(text)');
}
```

Can somebody please tell how this can be achieved?

Thanks in Advance..!!

Answer (score 2):

The way to use a parameter inside the function in the selector string is with [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Use back-ticks to create the selector string

```js
function myElement(text) {
  const selector = `span:contains(${text})`
  return cy.get(selector);
}
```

or shorter

```js
function myElement(text) {
  return cy.get(`span:contains(${text})`);
}
```

or custom command

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('findElementWithText', (text) => {
  cy.get(`span:contains(${text})`);
})
```

or using Cypress `contains()` does not need template literals

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('findElementWithText', (text) => {
  cy.contains('span', text);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Cypress custom command](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/custom-commands) to achieve this. Go to `cypress/support/commands.js` and write:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('findElementWithText', (text) => {
  cy.get(`span:contains(${text})`);
})
```

In your tests you can write:

```
cy.findElementWithText('randomText1')
cy.findElementWithText('randomText2')
```